# How does an Elasticsearch index of documents become an inverted index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know you can create an index, add documents to it and then list all of these documents using REST API. I know what an inverted index is. But how does one translate a list of documents into an inverted index? Both are called an "index", but is this the same index but mapped? Or a completely different index (so making an inverted index requires two indices)? If so, do I create it separately with a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Details here:

http://www.devinline.com/2018/09/elasticsearch-inverted-index-and-its-storage.html

> Elasticsearch uses a special data structure called "Inverted index" for very fast full-text searches. An inverted index consists of a list of all the unique words that appear in any document, and for each word, a list of the documents in which it appears. Inverted index is created from document created in elasticsearch. Inverted index is created using process called analysis (tokenisation and Filterization).

Comment: Thanks, but I know what an inverted index is - there are lots of material on the topic, as well as on the "documents index". I just can't grap how exactly they relate to each other.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the contents of the link? It does a decent job of explaining there with diagrams

Comment: I think I might have worded my question wrong. I understand the concepts separately as well as the fact that one stems from the other, I know what tokenization is. What I don't understand is how do they coexist practically. The diagram says it saves the inverted index into shards. If so - where are the original documents stored then? Not in shards? Different shards? How do I display the inverted index? Can I do it via REST API? Are they the same thing or two different indices? The word index is used so many times in the docs and it feels like every time it means something different.